# rails: can't select associated model with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

```
class Desk < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :reservations, dependent: :destroy
end
```

and

```
class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :desk
end
```

I want to get all desks on an date they are not reservated like this:

```
@free_desks = desks.select{|desk| desk.reservations.where.not(date: date)}
```

So when I have 8 desks for example and on date "2020-09-06" is desk(id: 1) reservated in Reservation model as an entry I wanna get 7 desks back.
But it doesn't work. Can someone help me out?

Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

So you want all Desks which have no corresponding reservations?

Try this:

```
Desk.left_joins(:reservations).where(reservations: {id: nil})
```

#### What does this mean?

You can think of us as trying to join two tables together. We are listing all the conversations - but some of them will not have any messages: the ids will be nil. We want to get them - hence we use the 'where' active record query method.

#### Warnings

You might get a million such records - which could overwhelm you. Watch out if you try to loop through them all in one hit.

#### Updated question:

```
date = Date.parse('january 5 2013')

Desk.left_joins(:reservations).where(reservations: {id: nil, date: date.beginning_of_day..date.end_of_day})
```

Note: This will likely assume UTC time (assuming you haven't changed any default settings).

Comment: Thank you very much I'll try it

Comment: But it doesnt filter by date. Tried this: Desk.left_joins(:reservations).where.not(reservations: { date: date}) But doesn't work currently. I try to figure out

Comment: I want all Desks, which have no reservations on an specific date

Comment: @MrGrashopper - that is a completely new question! In stack overflow you're not meant to completely change the quesiton like that. One should either ask the full question up front, or ask a completely new question

Comment: Sorry, but in my Question I mentioned it: "I want to get all desks on an date they are not reservated like this..."

Comment: But I got a workouraound: desk_arr = [] and then desks.each{|desk| desk&.reservations.each{|res| desk_arr << desk if res.date != date}}

Comment: @MrGrashopper that is not a scalable solution. In addition, you might get unexpected results depending on what you have set the date field to.

Comment: yes it's right. Got not what I want. Bad idea. Do you have a suggestion for me?

Comment: @MrGrashopper is the problem solved? if so can you pls mark this as solved?

Comment: I solved it with this dumb way: Desk.left_joins(:reservations).where(reservations: {id: nil}) + Desk.left_joins(:reservations).where.not(reservations: {date: date}) but I'm not happy with it. Idk why I can't get the deks by simply combining it the parameters how you

Comment: Try `date:date.beginning_of_day..date.end_of_day`